# Handling SQL Login/Passwords when deploying a VS Database Project (DACPAC)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, database-project, dacpac

After an initial publish to a SQL Server(2019) and after the initial create of my DB project (data tier app) when publishing again it is failing with a drift report. No changes done to the database externally or within the VS project.

Drift report:

```
<Modifications>
    <Object Name="[DummySqlLogin]" Parent="" Type="SqlUser" />
</Modifications>
```

To try and circumvent this by following a suggestion in answer on a [question/answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/149569/dacpac-and-database-drift-db-users-are-always-detected-as-drift-even-when-nothi) from 2016.

"From your publish config file, use the following"

```
<ExcludeUsers>True</ExcludeUsers>
<ExcludeLogins>True</ExcludeLogins>
```

Unlike the OP this does allow me to publish to my database which now leaves me to the question of how to deal with logins/passwords especially in a scenario where we are going to be publishing to different environments.

I was planning on using SQLCMDVARIABLES to maintain separate Publish profiles for different types of environments and within there could specify passwords for each and then within the VS Database Project place a PreDeployment script which would setup Logins/Passwords for SQL accounts and make use of the SQLCMD variables.

Is there no better way of doing this? This probably works great for when you only have 5-10 environments but what if you have a 100?

Note* I want to avoid using commercial tools such as Redgate.

Comment: With 100 different environments, use DB Roles for permissions and add the appropriate users to those. You really don't want to try to mess with login/user information for that many different environments and try to keep that up to date. I was able to do it in post-deploy scripts and variables, but that was for 4-5 environments for different/known domains. Trying to handle users and logins for 100's of environments is likely to lead to trouble no matter what tool you try to use for DB source control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one of common approaches:
*environments, deploy targets are no project sources.*

Same for specific logins, users, passwords. Those are security/administrations items server-specific. They depend on the environment, not product features. Why would the product, project sources depend on them? Imagine you have to change password due to security reasons on one of the servers. Can you logically connect it to recompiling all the sources?

I'd suggest to consider removing all the security items from SSDT project except maybe Roles (and configure publish.xml to ignore all the removed kinds of objects). Maintaining 100+ servers surely requires different tools and approaches, SSDT, dacpacs has nothing to do with it. The solution could be based on Octopus deploy, Ansible or something else.

Comment: If I do remove all security specific items, how do I then have these applied to the database? I tried setting up another separate database project but then that obviously evaluates all the other objects as well as the account management objects (users/logins/roles) and without manually excluding everything other type of object it won't work. It seems like I may be using the wrong type of project? As all I really want to do is separately execute a PostDeploy script (I can't have this in the actual database project because I'm having to maintain two separate types of scripts azure/sql).

Comment: SSDT is a wrong tool for anything you describe. "just scripts" can be executed with sqlcmd.

Comment: thanks I will go away and look at how I can maybe organise my series of sql scripts in a vs project that can be executed by sqlcmd and consumed by an azure pipelines or similar build system